# Sed & awk to replace string from JSON output

Tags: curl, awk, sed, jq

I am executing below command to get particular string from json output , here I am grepping with string "uri" which prints all the required fields.

```
# curl -X GET --insecure -H "$(cat /token/.bearer_header)" http://localhost:3000/api/search?query=% |  sed -e 
's/[{}]/''/g' | awk -v RS=',"' -F: '/^uri/ {print $2}' 
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  2410    0  2410    0     0  40166      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 40847
"ab/any-dashboard"
"ab/many-dashboard"
"ab/too-dashboard"
"ab/maximum-dashboard"
"ab/minimum-dashboard"
```

now I want to replace for example "ab/any-dashboard" to only any-dashboard, which means above command should print like below

```
any-dashboard
many-dashboard
too-dashboard
maximum-dashboard
minimum-dashboard
```

can anyone help me here I tried several things with sed but not getting exact result, and I dont have knowledge in JQ.

Regards,
SAM

Comment: Edit your question with the actual JSON being emitted instead of what remains after mangling with sed and awk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nE 's#".*/(.*)"#\1#p' file
```

Turn off implicit printing `-n`, and turn on extended regexp `-E` (`-r` on some platforms).

Pattern match on the required string and replace it with the expected part and print the result.

N.B. The `(...)` in the LHS of the substitution command is called a back reference and can be recalled in the RHS. Also the use of `#` as an alternative separator rather than the usual `/` which is part of the match.

Comment: this was the exact requirement and thank you for your explanation this will surely help me for future.

Answer (score 0):

If the awk statement below (which requires GNU awk for multi-char RS) is at the end of the command line, try adding this gsub function and see if you get what you want:

```
Current:
awk -v RS=',"' -F: '/^uri/ {print $2}'
```

Change to:

```
awk -v RS=',"' -F: '/^uri/ {gsub("/","-",$2);print $2}'
```

Comment: Potong has shared the exact command i was looking for, even your solution is very close to my requirement but it was not removing double quotes, thank you for you time and help  :)